# Using while loop for nested if statements

Tags: java, loops

Although I know I'm missing something, can't seem to get my head around a simple loop.

```
while (true){
if (n < 0)
    System.out.print("less than 0")
else if (n > 35)
    System.out.print("greater than 35")
else
    calc(n)    
}
```

I'm trying to use a `while loop` to loop the code and asks for input until the user inputs a value greater than 0 and less than 35, I have tried using continue but too no avail, thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWlWf.png)

I have added sc of full code, the while loop will go after requesting input at the bottom of the code

Comment: What does `calc(n)` do?

Comment: where are you asking for input? This is only output and `calc` that we cannot see - advice to read and post [mcve]

Comment: @Juan even when `n` changes, the loop is infinite because the `while(true)`. Isn't it?

Comment: Instead of ...else calc(n), try else break; and call calc(n) after the loop?

Comment: @lealceldeiro yes right

Comment: @prez you need two things here. If n < 0 or > 35, then you need to get input and update n. Otherwise, you need to exit the loop after doing your `calc(n)`.

Comment: So what after printing the message( if less than 0 or greater than 35)? Do you want to break the loop or you want next input?

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh I used the input In a static method, hence why its not included here

Comment: if you want to ask for input again and again than you need to ask and assign input to variable n inside loop before checking condition.. and if you want input only once then there is no need of loop..

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh alright, should I stil use the while true, or is that appropriate for this scenario

Comment: if you want to call calc method for multiple inputs then you should use while loop(you'll calling call method for different user inputs) but if you want only one input value and call calc for a single time then you don't need loop in main method.

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh im looping to ensure the user inputs a value In the desired range

Comment: @Prez means user must provide one correct value and after that program will do calculation and stop?

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh exactly, the correct value will be used to print a set of powers, hence I need one correct value

Comment: @Prez you can check the answer and please provide the feed back if something is wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // if using jdk 1.7 or above else close scanner in finally block.
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        int n;
        while (true) {
            n = s.nextInt();
            if (n < 0) {
                // ask for value greater then 0
                System.out.print("Please enter a value greater then 0 ");
                // extra print statement so input will be printed on next line after message
                System.out.println();
            } else if (n > 35) {
                // ask for value less then 35
                System.out.print("Please enter a value less then 35");
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                // process input and break if correct input has received
                calc(n);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you aren't "asking for input".  Also the while loop will NEVER exit. You probably at the minimum want a break in there somewhere.

Comment: I did, I should have shown in the code I provided.  my problem is looping until achieving required input

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the input for the user:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 0;
while (n != 27){ /*Can be any number here instead of 27, even -1*/
n = in.nextInt();
if (n < 0)
    System.out.print("less than 0")
else if (n > 35)
    System.out.print("greater than 35")
else
    calc(n)    
}
```

Also i would suggest you to not use ***while(true)*** becuase you will have endless loop, you can put instead a condition: ***while(n != 27)***

So each time you enter 27 it will end the loop.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem (However we can't tell since the OP has omitted relevant code). But, I think the problem is in the  `while(true)` part...

Comment: @Simion, how does the user exit your while loop?

Comment: @Simion, I was asking before you edited your condition. Which is still also a very strange condition.

Comment: It is just for example, it can be any conditions there, 27 is the ASCII code for key ESC (it has nothing to do in this case), so i somehow used to use this value in such places.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure of that calc method but maybe you could use something like this?

```
Boolean checked = true;
While(checked) {
 if (n < 0) {
    System.out.print("less than 0");
 }
 else if (n > 35) {
    System.out.print("greater than 35")'
 }
 else {
    calc(n)
    checked = false;
 } 
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: I tried this, if the user inputs a value greater than 35, it prints then the loop stops

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two things in your code.

1) Inside `while` loop, there is no mechanism to update the value of variable `n`. i.e, if outside loop, the value of n is set to say 2, the loop will keep on printing `Greater than 35`. So a mechanism is needed to update it's value

2) Breaking mechanism for `while` loop. Because the condition is `while(true)` and there is no `break` inside the loop, the loop will continue endlessly. So, a loop breaking mechanism is needed

Below is a sample code where input is taken from console using `Scanner` and `break` is used for loop breaking condition

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    while (true) {
        n = scan.nextInt();
        if (n < 0)
            System.out.print("less than 0");
        else if (n > 35)
            System.out.print("greater than 35");
        else {
            calc(n);
            break;
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: @Prez : So it is working as expected. If input would have been negative(less than zero), then it would have gone in `if` condition

Comment: @Prez: For input say, -1,-100, 36,67.... loop will continue until input is 0<n<35

Comment: @Prez Be sure to accept an answer that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way, it tells other people on the site that your question has been successfully solved.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n = 0;

   while (true){
         n = in.nextInt();
         if (n < 0)
            System.out.print("less than 0");
         else if (n > 35) 
            System.out.print("greater than 35");
         else{
            calc(n);
            break;
         }
     }
```

Comment: @PhilectorIV If the entered value is not in the desired range, it is never updated, leading to an infinite loop. You probably want to modify this to get some input.

Comment: It will continue to loop until n falls within the defined range.

Comment: Read your code again. How will n falls within the defined range when we are not updating it's value?

Comment: I'm tracking what you're saying. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

you can use do while. like this:

```
do {
   calc(n);
} while(n < 0 || n > 35)
```

expect calc(n) function read user input value and put it in n variable.

Comment: Wrong! n cannot be less than 0 AND greater than 35 at the same time so this will always evaluate to false.

Comment: This condition will never return true as no value can be less than 0 and greater then 35 at the same time... It shout be like &gt; 0 &amp; &amp; &lt;35

Comment: Correct sorry is an error. If we use || instead of && it can solv the problem. The meaning is just: repeat (read value of n) until n value is greater than 0 and less than 35.